# How to get the load event before ajax call to PHP returns

Tags: optimization, jquery

I would like my webpage to render faster. Based on this [article](http://blog.newrelic.com/2011/06/24/monitoring-user-experience-a-single-page-lifecycle/), I understand that the page renders when the 'load' event is fired.
When I look at the Network Tab of my Chrome browser, I see that the 'load' event is fired after an ajax call to a PHP script returns.

Webpage is live at http://www.99like.com/index.php

=> Is there any way to get the page to render before the PHP script is called?

Following is the extract of the code which I think is relevant for the question:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='images/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
    var inputForm = "<div class='shadow'><form type='submit' onsubmit='displayChart(); return false'><input id='searchBox' type='text' size='30' value='search keyword' /></form></div>";
    var chart = "<div id='chart' class='shadow'></div>";
    var chartPage = inputForm + chart;

    $(function ()
    {
        exampleChart();
    });

    function exampleChart() {
        $('#searchBox').val("hotel"); // nice example
        displayChart ();
    }

    function displayChart () {
        var keyword = $('#searchBox').val();

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({  ...  });

        chart.showLoading();

        var phpFunctionURL = "getChartData.php";
        var DataSeries; 
        $.ajax( {
            url: phpFunctionURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: { ... },  
            success: function(json) { DataSeries = json; }
        } ); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My comment answers your question and should allow you to gain loading speed as requested: have you tried it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few remarks:

1. Make sure all your JavaScript are at the bottom of the page, including JQuery and Google Analytics code
2. Your web-page is missing the end  tag
3. If needed, you could wait for the onLoad event to launch your AJAX request instead of the DomReady event, this will speed up the page rendering.

Comment: Richie Thank you. I was just puzzled with the #1 because I often see javascript in the <head> (like google analytics part for example). Also, by 'end tag' do you mean '</body>'?

Comment: @tucson #1: indeed, it is recommended to place JS at the bottom of a webpage to speed-up its initial rendering. The web-browser will render the HTML and CSS, then read and run the JS at the bottom of the page. #2: I was talking about the body indeed but it looks like it's been fixed. #3 is the one which will give you the most speed gain as the web-page will be rendered then the onLoad will run your AJAX call.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help. I did fix #2. I just tried #3 but it 'broke' the rendering of a default 'example graph'. Will look at it asap. Anyway thanks again for your help.

Comment: Correct answer by Jonjbar. I had issue with returned "Undefined"  when calling php from ajax and returning to the page. Once i put the jQuery API at the bottom of the page it got resoled. ! +5 !!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your AJAX request is synchronous. Making it asynchronous will solve the problem.

```
$.ajax( {
    url: phpFunctionURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true, // Changed from false to true
    data: { ... },  
    success: function(json) { DataSeries = json; }
} );
```